# Jquery $.post return null value

Tags: php, jquery

The following code is working perfectly on my localhost but after hosting the website. It is not returning the accurate value. If I use an alert to return the default value on the post code. A value is returned. For instance:

```
$.post('sendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
    if(data=="true"){
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('outline','1px solid #dce6f1');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('border','1px solid white');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('mouse','cursor');
        CurrentBtn.attr("disabled","disabled");
        CurrentBtn.removeAttr("href");

    }else if(data=="false"){
        alert('You have reached the maximum number of 5 offers you can send today');
        }else if(data=="not null"){
            alert("offer already sent");
        }else if(data=="assigned"){
            alert('This job is already assigned to another person');
        }else{
      alert(data);// a value is returned
}
    });
```

This is the JQuery Code:

```
$('.buyerRequest').click(function(){

    var CurrentBtn=$(this);
    var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');


$.post('sendingOffer.php',{id:id},function(data){
    if(data=="true"){
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('background','#dce6f1');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('outline','1px solid #dce6f1');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('border','1px solid white');
        CurrentBtn.html('<b>Offer Send</b>').css('mouse','cursor');
        CurrentBtn.attr("disabled","disabled");
        CurrentBtn.removeAttr("href");

    }else if(data=="false"){
        alert('You have reached the maximum number of 5 offers you can send today');
        }else if(data=="not null"){
            alert("offer already sent");
        }else if(data=="assigned"){
            alert('This job is already assigned to another person');
        }
    });

});
```

This the php code

```
<?php
require'set_session.php';
    require'../../../php/connection.php';
    $buyer_id='';
    $order_id='';
    $buyer_name='';
    $user_name=getUserField('user_name');

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
     $order_id=$_POST['id'];

    $query="select `account_id` from `place_order` where `order_id`='$order_id'";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
         $buyer_id=$row['account_id'];
        }
}


        $query="select `inbox_id` from `inbox` where `seller_name`='$user_name' and `date` ='".date("Y-m-d")."'";
        $query_run=mysql_query($query);
        $query_num=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        $queryExst="select `inbox_id` from `inbox` where `seller_name`='$user_name' and `order_id`='$order_id'";
        $query_runE=mysql_query($queryExst);
        $query_numE=mysql_num_rows($query_runE);
        $queryId="select `inbox_id` from `inbox` where `order_id`='$order_id' and `buyer_name` != ''";
        $query_runId=mysql_query($queryId);
        $query_numId=mysql_num_rows($query_runId);

        if($query_num < 5){
        if($query_numE==0){
            if($query_numId == 0){
            $query="insert into `inbox` values('','$buyer_id','$order_id','".date("Y-m-d")."','$user_name','','unread','unread','')";
            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
            echo'true';
        }else{
            echo'assigned';
        }

        }else{
            echo'not null';
        }
        }else{
            echo'false';
        }

?>
```

Comment: `.css('mouse','cursor');` is not valid CSS. You are also overwriting the button's HTML a whole lot. Something [like this](http://pastebin.com/rj52sZ1T) makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change the values  .css('cursor','pointer');

Comment: I think it is returning a value with a space ... How can i remove that space befor or after??

Comment: You can try to remove `?>`. It is not needed and may output unwanted stuff (like spaces or tabs). Also make sure the required  files do not output anything. Are you also certain that your PHP does not have any notices/warnings/errors? They will output error text. Press F12, open the Network tab, click the `sendingOffer.php` file and make sure its output is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Okey thanks let me try it out

Comment: Hae Sverri M.. stl is not working ... it is not executing any error

Comment: so the value it returns is "false" - as a string?